# Maven Classpath Command Line Arguments

Tags: java, maven-3

I am currently using Intellij IDE and Maven. I am having a bit of trouble adding a dependency to the classpath when using mvn exec.

I would like to add two JAR files to the classpath that currently have the "provided" scope in my pom.xml.

I have tried using classpath scope but that introduces an additional problem whereby another dependency is not being included as expected.

Is there any way to do this using the mvn exec command line arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [additionalClasspathElements](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#additionalClasspathElements) parameter to include the JAR files.